# Need to change firebase project in flutter application

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-authentication

I have published a app to play store and it contains  Google authentication with firebase. Now I need to replace the firebase project with other firebase project . Does this effect after publishing the app ?

Answer (score 2):

As you have uploaded the app, now in the existing application, you can not change the firebase project because the google-service.json file you included can not be changed now. All you can do is you can change that in the next build only. Just change the google-services.json with the new project JSON file and build another bundle and give the update.